# How to add section*{something} to the table of content?

Tags: table-of-contents

Today,I want to make the sections `Append A,B,C` in the `table of content`.However,I don't know how to do.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,cs4size,UTF8]{ctexart}                        
\usepackage{amsmath}                 
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}             
\usepackage{times}                  
\usepackage{fancyhdr}               
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=blue,anchorcolor=blue,citecolor=red,unicode]{hyperref}                   
\usepackage{lastpage}                
\usepackage{pdfpages} 
\pagestyle{fancy}                      
\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt}        
\fancyhf{}                            
\fancyhead[c]{常州大学本科生毕业论文}             
\fancyfoot[c]{第 \thepage 页,共\pageref*{LastPage}页} 

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}                           
 \tableofcontents                       
\end{titlepage} 

\section{Introduction}

\subsection{引言}
 babababababababbabababbabababbabababababbbaababbabababab
\newpage
\section*{Append A}
\newpage
\section*{Append B}
\newpage
\section*{Append C}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use after the `\section*{...}`:

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Append A or any other text}
```